# Getting a white page when testing new gem/engine. Logs show views rendering, but the page is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've been developing a gem/engine for a little bit, and using an existing app of mine to test it out. Everything has worked great. Then I went to add it to another app and suddenly it wasn't working. I figured it was because that app had some weird set up, but I've tried on a couple of other apps now and they all do the same thing.

When I go to visit the gem in the browser, the page is completely empty. It receives nothing from the server. No head, style, script, body. Just a blank page. I can visit other routes for these apps just fine and the pages load as expected. However, any of the routes added by the engine do this same load issue. The strangest part is: In my server logs, I see the correct controller hit, I see the views being rendered, I get the 200 OK at the end. I can do `puts` in the gem views and it will show up in the logs during the load process. There is absolutely no sign that anything went wrong anywhere, but yet... White page. I'm at a loss as where to even start debugging this. Does anybody have any experience with anything of the sort?

I created a new test app to verify and things worked as expected, but for some reason other existing apps have this issue.

Working apps:

```
Rails 5.0.2 
ruby 2.7.2p137
```

Fresh/blank app: (Working)

```
Rails 6.1.4
ruby 2.7.2p137
```

Apps that don't work:

```
Rails 6.1.3.1
ruby 2.7.2p137

Rails 6.1.4
ruby 3.0.2p107
```

I'm not even sure where to start debugging this as there is no "error" so I'm at a bit of a loss.

The repo for the gem is here: https://github.com/Rockster160/command_proposal but I'm mostly looking for thoughts on how to work through why this issue is happening and out how to debug it.

Comment: My first guess would be a naming conflict with the existing app.

Comment: @dbugger - It's unlikely, as everything in the gem is namespaced. Also one of the projects it fails on is pretty small, so doesn't have a lot of stuff to conflict with. Also why would that not throw an error?

Comment: Because it doesn't think it's an error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was caused because the app it was added in had links inside the layout. (Like a nav bar) I had a rescue block that caught those issues and attempted to look up the route in the main_app, however, that rescue still recognized that an error was thrown so rendered the empty file. It seems odd that would be the result, but I finally discovered that was the case.

To fix the routing issue, I had to include the main app routes as a helper in my main engine controller:

```
helper Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

However, this broke my engine routes, so I had to go through each of my engine's routes and explicitly call them off the engine.

```
tasks_path # Old way
command_proposal.tasks_path # New way
```